# How do I convert a screen position to geographic coordinates?

Tags: coordinates, algorithm

I'm looking for resources that explain how I should convert screen coordinates (the point that I pick on-screen) to geographic coordinates (lat / lon).

I want to build an application where, the simplified version, I can pick a point from an on-screen map and the geographic coordinates are passed to my database. I have a tile service that serves up raster tiles from a .MBTILES file, generated from OSM data stored in a Postgres databse. The client would likely be built with .NET, likely MVC for a web application or a WPF for a Windows desktop application.

I'm looking for concepts so I can do some additional research on my own in order to figure out what I need to do next. What are the best practices for doing this?

Comment: @MartinF I'm looking for concepts so I can do some additional research on my own in order to figure out what I need to do next. This part of the application be likely be .NET (MVC for web or WPF for desktop)

Comment: I'm glad you seek *concepts* and that is my forte. Others may be able to provide simple, specific instructions. Kudos for knowing you need to do more research.

Comment: Was my answer acceptable? Do you mind letting us know by “accepting” it (i.e., click the ✔ check) and “upvoting” (click the Λ arrow)? Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

First, it helps to know  what you are doing in generally used terms. In this case it is an *inverse projection* or a *reprojection* when you go from projected (or plane) coordinates "back" to geographic (or spheroidal) coordinates.

Second, you need to know what projected coordinate system you have on your screen, in order to specify the inverse. Not being familiar with OSM, and based, so far, only on this [show-a-kml-which-uses-longitude-and-latitude-epsg4326-in-google-osm-project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128178/show-a-kml-which-uses-longitude-and-latitude-epsg4326-in-google-osm-project), OSM uses the CRS (coordinate reference system) known as EPSG:3857.

Third, that CRS specifies not only the projection method but also the *datum* -- details of the ellipsoid used to represent Earth. It helps to understand that in order to properly do the next step. You need your geographic coordinates themselves to be on the correct datum/ellipsoid.

Fourth, you should find an existing software library/tool that, given your two CRSs -- projected and unprojected -- and some projected coordinates, transforms (unprojects) your coordinates into lat-long. PostGIS itself does some of that or use GDAL/OGR or others.

Since many reprojection tools only start from "real world" mapping units (e.g., m or ft) and your starting units are screen pixels, you *may* need a pre-step 4: convert your screen x-y pixels into ground X-Y units, based on the map scale. That is a simple scalar.

Comment: There a lot of synonyms in there to help or confuse. Ask here for clarification and i'll work on improving the answer...